# Clojure to Python: optional element in str like fn

Tags: python, clojure

Clojure version:

```clj
(defn greeting [& [name]]
  (cond-> "Hello" name (str " " name))
```

Naive Python version:

```py
def greeting(name=None):
    if name is None:
        name = ''
    else: name = ' ' + name
    return 'Hello' + name
```

Question: How to make the python version shorter and more idiomatic?

Comment: `return 'Hello '+name if name else 'Hello'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def greeting(name=''):
    return f'Hello {name}'.strip()
```

In case with `None` as default argument:

```
def greeting(name=None):
    return f'Hello {name}' if name else 'Hello'
```

Comment: Nitpick: the Clojure version would return `Hello` also when explicitly passing `nil` - assuming OPs use of `None` as arg, this would return `Hello None`.

Comment: @cfrick you are right, added variant for such case